# What is the difference between freeze user and deactivate user in Salesforce?

Tags: security, salesforce, organization

I am researching about Salesforce. I am read the session Control Access to Organization. I have not understand the difference between Deactivating or Freezing a User in Salesforce clearly. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, you can’t immediately deactivate an account, such as when a user is selected in a custom hierarchy field. To prevent users from logging in to your organization while you perform the steps to deactivate them, you can freeze user accounts.

If you freeze a user account, it gives you the opportunity to move the associated records, etc. to the ownership of someone else so they would be able to manage those accounts.  "Freezing" only stops the user from being able to login.  When you "deactivate," it frees up that salesforce license to be given to another user.

Comment: Thank for your answer

Answer (score 1):

*The difference is:

- Deactivate means that you dont allow that user login in your org and  it frees up that salesforce license to be given to another user.
- Freez just dont allow that user login in your org
  You can watch this video for more detail about the difference between Deactivating or Freezing a User in Salesforce: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYPB3oq_94Q